# Do heat-producing facilities recycle byproduct heat into their energy consumption?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity

Consider a steel mill or an ore smelting facility, what do they do with the heat they produce? On a consumer scale, heat pumps are a thing for decades (e.g. fridges), would this not be a feasible thing to do to reduce the costs of running the facility?

Comment: Are you asking if the waste heat could be used to keep the steel molten or close to its melting point?

Comment: or just in general if it could be used for anything, eg. an in-house steam turbine to help with the electricity bills.